# Problemas con get; set; Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, get, set

Soy muy nuevo programando en C#. Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio de *Windows* en el que primero se inicia sesión>se abre una ventana con dos opciones: visualización (un overlay con datos) y almacenamiento>en almacenamiento hay una pestaña llamada "DiveLogs"(FormDiveLogsMain)> en esta existe un label: *lblSupervisor*; debe reflejar el usuario que ingresó. lo que hice fue utilizar el método *get set*, se modifica el *value* al valor deseado, pero en la etiqueta no llega nada, queda vacia, se modifica el texto, pero como `null`. Por defecto la etiqueta contiene "Supervisor" como texto.

El proyecto "Presentacion" (donde se encuentra el Form "Login") posee un namespace distinto al namespace donde se encuentra el método *get set* (se encuentra en una clase llamada "Service"). Presentación posee como referencia al proyecto donde esta "service".

Este es el mapa del proyecto para que se entienda un poco mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instancia de Service Desde el Form "Login":

```
using Dominio;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using StartWindow;
using PracticaInterfaz_V2;
using PracticaInterfaz_V2.FormulariosHijos;

namespace Presentacion
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        public void BtnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (User.Text != "usuario")
            {
                if (Password.Text != "contraseña")
                {
                    UserModel user = new UserModel();
                    //var validLogin = user.LoginUser(User.Text,Password.Text);
                    
                    if (/*(validLogin == true && count==0) || */
                        (User.Text == "admin" && Password.Text=="admin" && count == 0))
                    {
                        StartWindowForm startMenu = new StartWindowForm();
                        MenuSupervision supervisionMenu = new MenuSupervision();
                        Service _service = new Service();

                        _service.Usuario = User.Text;                      
                        startMenu.Show();                       
                        
                        startMenu.FormClosed += Logout;
                        supervisionMenu.FormClosed += Logout;

                        count++;
                    }
                    else if(/*(count > 0 && validLogin == true) || */
                        (User.Text == "admin" && Password.Text == "admin" && count > 0))
                    {
                        msgError("Sólo se admite un usuario por sesión.");
                    }
                    else msgError("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta");
                    Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
                    Password.Text = "contraseña";
                    User.Focus();
                }
                else msgError("Porfavor ingrese la contraseña");
            }
            else msgError("Porfavor ingrese el usuario");
        }
        #endregion

        private void msgError(string msg)
        {
            ErrorMsglbl.Text = "" + msg;//aumentar espacio en caso de agregar imagen de advertencia
            ErrorMsglbl.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Logout(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            User.Clear();
            Password.Clear();
            ErrorMsglbl.Visible = false;
            User.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticaInterfaz_V2
{
    public class Service
    {
        public string Usuario
        {
            get { return _usuario; }
            set { if (value != null) _usuario = value; }
        }
        private string _usuario;
    }
}
```

Se instancia a Service en FormDiveLogsMain:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PracticaInterfaz_V2;

namespace PracticaInterfaz_V2.FormulariosHijos
{
    public partial class FormDiveLogsMain : Form
    {
        Service _service;    

        public FormDiveLogsMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _service = new Service();
        }

        private void FormDiveLogsMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblNum.Visible = true;
            lblSupervisor.Visible = true;
            
            lblSupervisor.Text = _service.Usuario;           
            lblNum.Text = lastAddedItemDive.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Intenté modificando una variable ubicada en el destino desde Login, pero tampoco funcionó. Espero me puedan ayudar. muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Tengo entendido que si creas una clase como por ejemplo `sessionData.cs` con los datos de la sesión iniciada, cuando lo quieras consumir luego vas a tener los datos que necesites...
Por ejemplo, creas la clase así: public class sessionData { public static string usrLogueado; } y en el LogIn completas este dato con sessionData.usrLogueado = txtUsuario.Text... Luego desde tu otra ventana podrías hacer lo siguiente: lblSupervisor.Text = sessionData.usrLogueado

Comment: Al crear el objeto "_service" en la clase FormDiveLogsMain asignas un nuevo objeto vacio, y por ello devuelve null, solo debes agregar que en el constructor reciba un obj Service como parametro y asignarlo al _service de la clase.

Comment: @Matias Tengo entendido que para ello debiese crear un Using Presentacion; en el lugar de destino, pero no puedo crear una dependencia circular; el proyecto Presentacion ya posee como referencia al proyecto del namespace de FormDiveLogsMai

Comment: @Gervera Gracias por responder. Perdón si no entiendo bien, pero te refieres a esto?:
Service _service;    public FormDiveLogsMain(){_service = _service.Usuario;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias a todos por responder. Pude resolverlo dejando como static las variables en la clase service, sin instanciar un objeto de la clase service en ningun lado.
En Login.cs queda como:

```
Service.Usuario = User.Text;
```

En la clase Service como:

```
 public static string Usuario
    {
        get { return _usuario; }
        set { if (value != null) _usuario = value; }
    }
    private static string _usuario;
```

y en la clase de destino FormDiveLogsMain como:

```
lblSupervisor.Text = Service.Usuario;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando una nueva instancia en tu FormDiveLogsMain haces un new Service(); por esa razón tu usuario siempre será vacío

```
 public FormDiveLogsMain( Service service_)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _service = service_
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @Samuel por responder. Al aplicar la modificación me arroja error: 
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'service_' of 'FormDiveLogsMain.FormDiveLogsMain(Service)' PracticaInterfaz_V2 

En el evento del botón que llama a FormDiveLogsMain()

 private void BtnDivelogs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ActivarBtn(sender, RGBColors.color1);
            AbrirFormHijo(new FormDiveLogsMain());

        }

Comment: Porque la respuesta, aunque es un buen intento, no esta completa. OP cambio el constructor del formulario, y ahora siempre requiere de un parametro, que por ejemplo el diseñador no le va a mandar, y vos no le estas pasando tampoco.